# Copy moviClip doesn't work, it only displays a quarter of image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I try to copy a moviclip but the created bitmap only displays a quarter of the movieClip which I want to duplicate

```js
var insName:String="a1";
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(m1.getChildByName(insName).width,m1.getChildByName(insName).height);
myBitmapData.draw(m1.getChildByName(insName) as MovieClip);
var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
bm.x = 1800;
bm.y = 100 ;
addChild(bm);
```

Comment: Do `trace((m1.getChildByName(insName) as MovieClip).getBounds())` Most likely your MC has parts in the negative coords. To fix, make a matrix that'll translate (0,0) to the top left corner of rectangle returned by `getBounds()` call, and supply it to `BitmapData.draw()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import flash.geom.Matrix;
```

Then change this:

```
var mcTemp:MovieClip=m1.getChildByName(insName);
myBitmapData.draw( mcTemp,new Matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1,  mcTemp.width/2, mcTemp.height/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your movie is scaled, yet you are using its scaled size to create your bitmapdata but drawing ignores transformations so it draws it unscaled. From what you say it seems your movie is scaled at 0.5 likely. Other situations might be possible but if your movie is scaled a simple fix could be:

```
var child:DisplayObject = m1.getChildByName(insName);
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(child.width / child.scaleX, child.height / child.scaleY);
```

Comment: You must multiply not divide!

Comment: Multiply or divide , result is still a quarter

Comment: do you see any black around your bitmapdata?

Comment: There was no black space background was transparent

Comment: when not specified (only pass width and height) a bitmapdata is created opaque with 0 color (black). The fact that you say it's transparent means that you did not provide the correct code and correct situation.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question is blank, background is blank, and also as you said drawing ignores transformaition. thus I have another problem, now my duplicated moviclips displays image but some lose aroung corners

Comment: according to the accepted answer your movie has a center registration, besides that I don't see any other problems. What do you mean by lose around corners?

Answer (score 0):

according to @Vesper's comment, I think better to use this for your bitmap data:

```
var myBitmapData:BitmapData=new BitmapData(child.getBounds().width,child.getBounds().height)
```